# String.replaceOccurrences(of:with:) not working?

Tags: swift, string, swift3

Simple problem, tricky solution: I have a string which includes spaces and I want to get rid of them but calling `replaceOccurrences(of:with:)` doesn't do anything.

```
let originalString:String = "+005 78 34 56"
let stringWithoutSpaces:String = originalString.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
print(stringWithoutSpaces)
```

`stringWithoutSpaces` is exactly the same as `originalString`. Could this be an Xcode bug or am I overlooking something?

**UPDATE:**

A screenshot of the code in my project.
[image: Screenshot 1]

And a screenshot of the debug log to verify the original string contained spaces:
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: That code does not compile, there can be no output which is the same as the original string or not.

Comment: @MartinR I typed this on my iPhone, so that's how the typo sneaked in there. I ran my project a bazillion times, and I always let Xcode autocomplete method names, so the typo is definitly not the issue.

Comment: I copied the new version of your code (revision 4) into a Xcode project, and the output was `+005783456` ...

Comment: @MartinR I didn't update any code, I merely fixed the typos you pointed out. And this is literally the only string related code in my project, so if this code is working for you it must be a bug or I did something really really weird somewhere in my project. I'll try to get some screenshots.

Comment: WHY DO I KEEP GETTING DOWNVOTED FOR HAVING A QUESTION?!

Comment: It wasn't me (yet) but it is expected that you post a *reproducible* example demonstrating your problem (see "Help others reproduce the problem" in http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The first version of your question did not compile, the current version does not exhibit the problem. – What answer do you expect with the given information?

Comment: @MartinR Primarily whether this code is supposed to work like this, or whether I perhaps forgot to do something (which is literally what I asked in my post). If it's the first case, perhaps I could get some suggestions on things I could try to figure out the source of my problem. If no one has any idea what to do, it would be fair to assume it's a software bug and I could close this thread.  So basically, according to Stack's guidelines, a question either gets answered correctly or it gets downvoted, right? There's nothing in between these two things?

Comment: @MartinR I'm wondering if they realize that 9 out of 10 times it's practically impossible to "reproduce a problem". Do they expect me to copy my entire Xcode project on here, because then I would have a serious job on my hands copying 20000 lines of code from 30+ different Swift files. I will copy the actual code where the issue occurs among the method in which the code is being called, but I know it won't make any sense to anyone who doesn't know all the ins and outs of the project I'm working on, so why bother?

Comment: The challenge is to create a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example": http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @MartinR How did I not do that in my post? Which of these three components is missing? I even specifically made it as minimal as possible.

Comment: The *"Verifiable – Test the code you're about to provide to make sure it reproduces the problem"* component is missing. As I said above, the code in your question works as expected, it prints `+005783456`, with all spaces removed. The output of that code is not, as you claim, the same as originalString.

Comment: @MartinR IT IS for me! THAT's the whole problem! The problem is not that `replaceOccurrences` doesn't remove the spaces, the problem is that it doesn't do that FOR ME! I'm merely describing what my experience is while running this code, I'm not claiming that this is what the code is supposed to be doing for everyone!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127576/discussion-between-martin-r-and-freddy-benson).

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `:` to `=`. That should fix it.

```
let str = "Hello, playground"
let withoutSpaces = str.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
// result: "Hello,playground"
```

If you are not getting the desired result you should check if

- the value is correctly read from the correct variable
- the value is correctly displayed
- the value is not changed back before being displayed
- the input value is what you expect

Comment: What `:` are you talking about?

Comment: Look at your and my version and notice the difference. These marks are important!

Comment: The only `:` I'm using is to specify the constant type, not to assign any values to it. I've been programming for a while now, I'm not making these kind of noob mistakes and even if I were, Xcode would give me a syntax error...

Comment: The above works as expected in Playground. Check the things on the list.